# PHP Mail: special characters show different between Firefox and IE

Tags: php, email, browser, special-characters

I have a problem when sending a form via email using the PHP Mail function. This is the code that I'm using:

```
$name  = $_POST['name'];
$last_name  = $_POST['last_name'];
$company  = $_POST['company'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$country = $_POST['country'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$message = $_POST['message']); //This comes from the form

$formcontent="Name: $name $last_name <br> Company: $company <br> Email: $email <br> Country: $country <br> Telephone: $phone <br><br> Message: $message";

$mailheader  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$mailheader .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8 Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable' . "\r\n";
$mailheader .= 'From: ' . $email . "\r\n";

mail("my@email.com", "subject", $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");
```

This is a form that will be sending spanish and special characters, like ñ, accents, ç, etc...

The problem is that, if I use it like this, it works fine in Firefox 3.6.3, but when using the form in Internet Explorer 8, the special characters that sends are all messed up (like Ã§ instead of a ç). However, if I add **utf8_encode** to the variables in the **$formcontent**, then it works in IE, but it stops working in Firefox, showing stuff like η instead of ç.

What can I do to make it work regardless of the browser? Any help would be much appreciated!

**EDIT:**

I've noticed that, if I echo the **$formcontent** variable before sending it with **mail**, if I'm using Firefox, the special characters are already messed-up. How can I avoid the browsers interfering with what's being sent? Please I'm totally clueless right now!!! I don't know what to change to have something working. Even if it's a dumbed down version, is there any alternative to have PHP Mail working with special characters in both browsers?

Comment: You mean "Internet Explorer"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you need to make sure that every charset on your page is the same. Make sure the page has a utf-8 charset aswel. Since you're sending it in utf8 the input must come from utf8 aswell.

Could you perhaps show us the code of the page (or a live demo) where the mail is being made?

Comment: @PENDO: thanks for your reply. I have this in my page's header: **<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />**. And the form's tag is: **<form id="form1" action="" method="POST" accept-charset="UTF-8">**. So everywhere I see it says UTF-8...

Comment: is it possible that your IE browser is overriding the charset with another (ISO-8859 for example)

Comment: @PENDO: well, the thing is that someone else's Explorer is doing the same... How can I check if that's what's happening? Anyways, do you see anything weird in my code? Is that the way you would do it?

Comment: I'm using PHPMailer to send my e-mails, I've stopped using these methods as PHPMailer is a complete package and simple to use. You might wanna check that out.

Comment: @PENDO: do you think that would help with the special characters issue?

Comment: I fixed it changing everything to **ISO-8859-1**, and it now it works in both browsers. Don't know why it wasn't working with UTF-8, but whatever... Thanks PENDO for your help!

Comment: You're welcome, not sure what the problem was (seems weird), but usually these classes (such as PHPMailer) provider a complete package of automatically runned functions to create the right headers and stuff. I've struggled before with the mail() function, but since I've used PHPMailer, that's all I'm gonna do in the future :)